# LD_PRELOAD which program is target

Tags: c, linux, ld-preload, start-stop-daemon

Is there a way to figure out which program is the one being targeted by a LD_PRELOAD?

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libstuff.so ./stuff <args>
```

Like when building the `libstuff` library in C/C++ and when it's preloaded is there a way to figure out that the program targeted is  `stuff`?

And is this a safe way of doing so by if it were the case that the file is `stuff` then do things and else just let the lib die.

IF this is not recommended

The reason for asking is I can't get

```
HOME=$WORK_PATH start-stop-daemon --start --chuid servers --quiet --background --nicelevel -1 --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --exec $WORK_PATH/program <args>
```

to work with `LD_PRELOAD` targeting `program` and not `start-stop-daemon`

I don't know if this is allowed going offtopic like this (sorry incase) but if someone could help me with that would make my day too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it using the `env` program, which modifies the environment then calls `exec`:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --chuid servers --quiet --background --nicelevel -1 --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile \
   --exec env "LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libstuff.so" "HOME=$WORK_PATH" "$WORK_PATH/program" <args>
```